# Total mechanical energy concept

Tags: energy

I was solving a true or false question regarding total mechanical energy and the following was the problem.

> It is possible for a moving object to have negative total mechanical energy.

This is my claim.

Total mechanical energy is defined as

$$M=K+U$$

where $K=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and $U=mgh$.

No matter which direction the object is moving $K$ must be positive due to the $v^2$. (I am assuming that mass is also never negative.)

Potential energy is also positive because $g=9.8$ and height is a distance, which is also non-negative.

And yet, the problems says that the answer is true, as in the total mechanical energy is allowed to be negative.

What am I not seeing here ?

Comment: Are you sure height is necessarily a non-negative distance?

Comment: What ? Are you suggesting that height can be negative? as in, the object still moving after it hits the ground and go inside ?

Comment: Relative to your head, how far away are your feet?

Comment: I see, so relativity is the issue. That makes sense. So, considering the top of a building 1km below a plane, an object that is falling on the ground can have negative mechanical energy while it's still moving. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kyle implies in the comments, mechanical energy is generally defined only up to a constant. Therefore, if you choose your constant as a large, negative number, you could have a total energy that is negative even with a very fast moving particle. Likewise, if you choose your potential energy to equal zero at, say, the top of a cliff, then anything you throw off the cliff will have negative potential energy once it falls below your feet.

This is not strictly a duplicate, but it is probably worthwhile to link to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90231/can-a-particle-have-momentum-without-energy/90233#90233) answer I posted a while back.

Comment: I like using $mgy$ instead of $mgh$. Makes the arbitrary nature of origin more apparent.